# Why do 3 carbon allotropes, create a plasma, when placed in a microwave oven of at least 1100 watts, but diamond does not?

Tags: energy

When placing powdered carbon, be it graphite, amorphous carbon, (charcoal and ash), or graphene oxide, in a household microwave oven, rated at least 1100 watts, the subject matter creates or causes plasma to appear within 60 seconds of pressing the cook button. However, diamond dust does not demonstrate this under those conditions. It should also be noted, that after microwave irradiation, (2.4 GHz) and production of plasma, the carbon exhibits super-paramagnetism, which it does not prior to the irradiation. What is happening and how can I measure the temperature of said plasma? I have videos of this experiment if so desired.

Comment: Because your first three are metallic in nature, and diamond is a wide band gap semiconductor that can't absorb microwaves well at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! 1.) Is it the crystal structure of the carbon allotropes, the density, the electron configuration, or the type of carbon=carbon bonding that is the major factor determining "metallic in nature"? 2.) Do you have any thoughts as to why the first 3 allotropes become super paramagnetic? My thought is that allotropes give up an electron leaving an odd number of electrons